# How to connect to database connection in Java

Tags: java, database, jdbc, xampp

I would like to know how to connect to database in which is hosted in Xampp MySQL.

This is what I have so far in my java code to connect but I'm unsure what I'm doing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection( host, username, password );
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
        String uName = "root";
        String uPass= "password";
    }
    catch ( SQLException err ) {
    System.out.println( err.getMessage( ) );
    }

}
```

1. What would the host URL be?
2. Do i need a JDBC Jar file to connect to the DB?

I have setup a database and table via phpMyAdmin already. Just don't know how to proceed.

I am using **Netbeans** to write my Java code to connect to a local database which was created via **Xampp PHPMyAdmin**.

In the end, I want to create a database connection in Java and call out tables within the IDE. Would appreciate some help.

Comment: did you get an error when you try to connect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the project structure

[image: Project Structure]

Try with this

**Update**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Where is your MySQL JDBC Driver?");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("MySQL JDBC Driver Registered!");
    Connection connection = null;

    try {
        connection = DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testspring","root", "password");

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

    if (connection != null) {
        System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
    }
}
```

It is working for me

I downloaded jar from [Java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjavajar.htm)

[Refer](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

Comment: Question. Where do I add the jar file? To my Netbeans Project directory? and Do i have to copy all files from the zip file ?

Comment: Create a folder lib and add the jar their

Comment: Do I have to rename the jar file or leave the naming conventions as it is? Also what code can I write to mention that the connection to the database has been successful?

Comment: leave it like that, that is fine. for your next question see the edit

Comment: Doesnt seem to work somehow. I placed it right after the Connection opening declaration, but its somehow not calling out the `println` statement.

Comment: I see why it didn't work. It's because that I had to manually add the JAR file to the project via Netbeans. Right click on the project folder > Properties > Libraries > Add JAR file. It works!

Comment: The right way to add library is copy the jar in lib folder, then right click on your project->Properties->Java Build Java-> Add Jars(then select the jar from the lib folder) -> Ok

Answer (score 2):

This is a code (Java 7 style, try-with-resources, more laconic style) to connect and retrieve data from your DB.

```
 public static final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM your_table_name";
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Employees";
    String uName = "root";
    String uPass = "password";

    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
         Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_QUERY)) {

        while (rs.next()) {
            //read your lines one ofter one
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String somePropertyValue = rs.getInt("some_column_name");
            // etc. 
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also, add JDBC driver (*.jar file) in your classpath if you are running from command line, or add this jar to your project, if you are working in IDE (Eclipse, IDEA etc. It is a little bit different for each one).

BTW, How your code compiled if variable declaration is after they using? That code can not be compiled even.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should define your strings before use them.

The host URL seems good.

You have to install the driver in your server, or to put it in the `/lib` folder of your project. You fill find it in `%DERBY_HOME%/lib` folder, named `derby.jar`, assuming `%DERBY_HOME%` is the directory installation of Derby.

Comment: I believe I'm using mysql, which means I need to change the url path to the following right, `String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_test14";`? Please advise.

Comment: You're right, assuming MySQL is on the port 3306 and your database name is `db_test14`. Then you will need a [MySQL JDBC driver](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;



public class DatabaseUtil1 {

    public static final String DRIVER="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
    public static final String URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@DIPAK-PC:1521:xe";
    public static final String USERNAME="system";
    public static final String PASSWORD="password";

    public static Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        Connection con= null;

        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);

        System.out.println(con);
        return con; 
    }
    public static void closePreparedStatement(PreparedStatement pst) throws SQLException
    {
        if(pst!=null)
        {
            pst.close();
        }

    }
    public static void closeConnection(Connection con) throws SQLException
    {
        if(con!=null)
        {
            con.close();
        }

    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the packages: Requires that you include the packages containing the JDBC classes needed for database programming. Most often, using import java.sql.* will suffice.

Register the JDBC driver: Requires that you initialize a driver so you can open a communication channel with the database.

Open a connection: Requires using the DriverManager.getConnection() method to create a Connection object, which represents a physical connection with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Database connectivity: these are the steps required to connect Java application to a database.

- Import the sql package

  ```
  Import.java.sql.*;
  ```
- Load driver

  Every database has different driver, we are using SQL database so driver for SQL database is

  ```
  Class.forName(“com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”);
  ```
- Make Url

  ```
  String url=”jdbc:mysql://localhost/DataBaseName”;
  ```
- Make connection

  ```
  Connection con=DriverManager(url,”root”,””);
  ```
- Create statement object

  ```
  Statement st = con.CreateStatement();
  ```

  After creating statement object, we can perform SQL queries on the database.
- Make query

  ```
  String sql = "SELECT * FROM table_Name ";
  ```
- Create ResultSet object and execute query

  ```
  ResultSet rs = st.excuteUpdate(sql);
  ```
- Important step to close the connection

  ```
  con.close();
  ```

**Note** if we do not have SQL connecter in jdk first download connector from this url:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html

and copy and paste into:

```
Java/jre/lib/ext
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DbOperations {
  Connection con;
  PreparedStatement ps;
    public DbOperations() {
        con = DbUtil.getConnection();
    }
    public boolean insertSubject(String name) throws SQLException {
    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "insert into subject (name) values ('"+ name +"')";
     ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);
// ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.executeUpdate();
    if(ps!= null){
        System.out.println("successfull!!");
      return true;
    }else {
    return false;
    }
  
    }
    public ArrayList getSubjectById(int id) throws SQLException {
   
     Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from subject where id = '"+ id +"'";
     ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
   ArrayList<Object> records=new ArrayList<Object>();
while(resultSet.next()){
    // subject sub = new subject();
    // sub.id = resultSet.getInt(1);
    // sub.name = resultSet.getString(2);
    // records.add(sub.id);
    // records.add(sub.name);
    records.add(resultSet.getInt(1));
    records.add(resultSet.getString(2));
    System.out.println("record output:" + records );
}

return (ArrayList) records;
    }

    public ResultSet getAllSubjects() throws SQLException {
 Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from subject";
     ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
        return resultSet;
  }
  
    public boolean insertStudent(String student_name, float score, String name) throws SQLException {

    Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select id from subject where name = '"+ name +"'";
     ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
     int subId =0;
    while(resultSet.next()){
      subId = resultSet.getInt(1);
    }

    String sql1 = "insert into student (student_name,score,subject_id) values ('"+ student_name+"','"+score+"','"+subId+"')";

    int result = s.executeUpdate(sql1);
    if(result==0){
      return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
    
    }
    public ArrayList getStudentyId(int id) throws SQLException {

Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from student where id = '"+ id +"'";
     ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
   ArrayList<Object> records=new ArrayList<Object>();
while(resultSet.next()){
    // student sub = new student();
    // sub.id = resultSet.getInt(1);
    // sub.student_name = resultSet.getString(2);
    // sub.score = resultSet.getFloat(3);
    // sub.subject_id = resultSet.getInt(4);

    // records.add(sub.id);
    // records.add(sub.student_name);
    // records.add(sub.score);
    // records.add(sub.subject_id);
    records.add(resultSet.getInt(1));
    records.add( resultSet.getString(2));
    records.add(resultSet.getFloat(3));
    records.add(resultSet.getInt(4));

}
return (ArrayList) records;

}
    public ResultSet getAllStudents() throws SQLException {
        Statement s = con.createStatement();
    String sql = "select * from student";
     ResultSet resultSet = s.executeQuery(sql);
        return resultSet;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code. This will work

```
import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  
//here is database name, root is username and password  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  
while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  
con.close();  
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
}  
}
```

Comment: You have not addressed the two questions in the OP, and you've added additional code which assumes a certain schema. You have also not provided any explanation on your solution or how they should modify it for their environment.